# To dismiss the keyboard upon entering the last OTP digit

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios, custom-renderer

I am working on a concept which has a OTP screen.
The requirement is to dismiss the keyboard automatically upon entering the last digit of the 6 digit OTP number.

Here is what I have done till now -

```
if (lastOTPEntry.Value != string.Empty)
{
    lastOTPEntry.Unfocus();
}
```

Then I have an `EntryRenderer` which overrides this method -

```
protected override void OnFocusChangeRequested(object sender, VisualElement.FocusRequestArgs e). 
{ 
   if (Control != null). 
   {    
        if (e.Focus)
        {
             Control.RequestFocus();
        }
        else
        {
            Control.ClearFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

`Control` is a `FormsEditText`
But somehow the keyboard does not dismiss.
What am I doing wrong here .. ?

Comment: Have you tried `ResignFirstResponder` ?

Comment: This issue only observed in Android, works as expected in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to do something similar in older project and ended up using a service pattern to implement.

Android Service:

```
public class KeyboardService : IKeyboardService
{        
    public void HideKeyboard()
    {
        var context = Application.Context;
        var inputMethodManager = context.GetSystemService(Context.InputMethodService) as InputMethodManager;

        if (inputMethodManager != null && context is Activity)
        {
            var activity = context as Activity;
            var token = activity.CurrentFocus?.WindowToken;

            inputMethodManager.HideSoftInputFromWindow(token, HideSoftInputFlags.None);
            activity.Window.DecorView.ClearFocus();
        }
    }
}
```

iOS Service:

```
public class KeyboardService : IKeyboardService
{
    public void HideKeyboard()
    {
        UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.EndEditing(true);
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
public interface IKeyboardService
{
    void HideKeyboard();
}
```

To use, you'll need to register it with your dependency service the resolve it. After it's resolved, to use it:

```
if (lastOTPEntry.Value != string.Empty)
{
    keyboardService.HideKeyboard();
}
```

I haven't touched that project in a while but the logic should still work.

Comment: This works ! But what could be possibly wrong in the code that I have mentioned in the question..?

Comment: Not sure. Some quick looking around the internet seems to show that you can't just clear focus, you have to give something else focus.

Comment: I too did some searching and ended up adding ‘base.onFocusChangeRequested’ and removing ‘control.clearfocus’ and it started to work. Any idea how ? What changed by calling the parent method ..?